# Get sender email address

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the following VBA code which is meant to send an automatic email when a specific subject is received.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
If item.Class = olMail Then
    If Left$(item.Subject, 29) = "Hazard Identification Report" Then
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim NewForward As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

        Set Msg = item
        Set NewForward = Msg.Forward
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        strSender = ""
        strSenderName = Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress

        If itm.SenderEmailAddress = "EX" Then
            Set objSender = itm.Sender
            If Not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
                Set objExchUser = Sender.GetExchangeUser()
                If Not (objExchUser Is Nothing) Then
                    strSender = objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            End If
        Else
            strSender = itm.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
```

I'm getting a compile/object error at the following line:

```
strSenderName = Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

the sender name comes up as "empty".

How I can extract the sender's email address?

Comment: Why not `msg.SenderEmailAddress`?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! It had to be something simple. @Siddharth Rout if you can put that as the answer, ill mark it as complete.

Comment: how come you have variable `item` in top half of the code and them suddenly `itm`? And there are no `Set Sender = ...` line at all, so it's Empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Originally answered in comments.

> Why not msg.SenderEmailAddress

Comment: in a perfect world maybe, but not for active directory senders.

Answer (score 8):

Above accepted answer did not work for me. Instead, I'm using this (works with MeetingItems too):

```
Function GetSenderEmail(oM As Variant)

   Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
   Set oPA = oM.PropertyAccessor

   GetSenderEmail = oPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E")

End Function
```

Thanks to David Lee for the solution in [this thread](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28169495/Different-ways-of-retrieving-the-sender-of-an-email-in-Outlook-VBA.html#answer39309990-20).